# Função angular 2 similar a Toggle Jquery

Tags: angular, toggle

Preciso fazer algo similar ao toggle do jQuery, numa página de FAQ.
Caso o usuário clique na pergunta então exibir a resposta abaixo, caso clicar de novo ocultar.. porém, estamos utilizando angular 2 e vi que existe várias classes/funções que tratam de animations, mas não consegui entender/implementar encontrei nenhum exemplo que faça isso...(sou iniciante em angular..) 
Um site de exemplo que implementa o toggle: http://www.maujor.com/blog/pg_apoio/jquery-toggle-texto-exemplo.html

Alguém poderia me ajudar implementando um exemplo de toggle utilizando angular 2? (https://angular.io/api )

Answer (score 0):

Por quê não utilizar o simples, apenas com HTML 5?

```html
<details>
  <summary>Em que site estou?</summary>
  <p>Está no Stack Overflow em Português</p>
</details>
```

Comment: Bacana esta tag, não a conhecia. Simples e fácil, mas com um porém, sempre tem que ter né? IE ela não funciona, não tem suporte em nenhuma versão. :/

Comment: Bem observado. Havia esqueci de olhar o "can i use".